# What are some resources for learning the ins and outs of .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess

What are resources for learning the various things I can do with .htaccess?

Answer (score 6):

[Stupid htaccess tricks](http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/), despite the name and colour scheme it's not stupid.

Comment: Clicked on this question with the intent of posting that link.  Great resource.

Comment: But whatever you do, don't use the snippet to "limit server request methods to GET and PUT".  The HEAD verb is **Critical** to cacheability.

Answer (score 3):

The official Apache docs:

- [Apache HTTP Server Tutorial: .htaccess files - Apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) **//** [Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) **//** [Current](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)
- [Apache Module mod_rewrite - Apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) **//** [Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) **//** [Current](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

Answer (score 1):

- [htaccess - Ultimate Apache .htaccess file Guide](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my favourite one:

- [.htaccess tips and tricks](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php) (Part 1)

Make sure you read part two as well that covers mod_rewrite:

- [more .htaccess tips and tricks...](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php) (Part 2)